# Save new id into old table

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to move data from these old tables

```
restaurant_id | restaurant_nm | more data

bar_id | bar_nm | more data
```

To

```
venue_id | venue_nm
```

I'll add field venue_id to the old tables
Then I want to run a query similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO `venue` (SELECT null, `restaurant_nm` FROM `restaurant`)
```

However, while do the copy I want the new id to be stored into the old table. Is this possible with pure mysql?

**Edit** The old restaurants can be chains (multiple messy joe's), the only thing that identifies them 100% is the id

Comment: how is the new ID calculated?

Comment: the new id is an auto increment

Comment: important to ask whether restaurant and bar id's share any common values

Comment: The restaurant id and the bar id can be the same number, that's why we want a unique venue id

Comment: thought so.   so my below suggestion will be repeated for bar_id.

Answer (score 1):

You could temporarily store the old ID in the new table (in an extra column) and then do an UPDATE on the old table.  That's two lines of 'pure SQL.'

```
restaurant_id |restaurant_name | v_id

venue_id | venue_name | rest_id

INSERT INTO `venue` (SELECT null, `restaurant_nm`, `restaurant_id`  FROM `restaurant`)
```

and then

```
UPDATE restaurant r
INNER JOIN venue v
ON r.restaurant_id = v.rest_id
SET r.v_id = v.venue_id
```

Interested to see what a more elegant solution might be.

Comment: I'm assuming here that the restaurant and venue id's, and bar and venue id's, may not be equal.

Comment: Thanks, this is the last solution, as I will have to do this with bar's, schools, hospitals, bakeries, police stations, ATMs and another 15 tables or so

Comment: ah.  you could generalize the approach maybe, by storing the id's in a middle table [old_id, venue_id]. then adding that to the join. and deleting from it after every table was updated.  so you wouldn't have to add new columns all over the place.

Comment: But that middle table old_id collumn would have multiple values of 1,2,3 because the old tables all have their own id's from  1 to n

Comment: No, because you can just delete from it in between uses.  (That is, in between updating each table.)     You only need the data for the time it takes to run the 2nd update.    You'll also need a way to store ID's from that INSERT SELECT into venues (a cursor approach, maybe.)   It's a bit of work, but probably worth it if you have 15+ tables to do?   I'll try and update my original answer.

Comment: Only 23 views, I guess I will accept this answer although I was also `Interested to see what a more elegant solution might be.`